# Download, Install and Delete the Apk programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm making an Android App where the requirement is to place the apk on the website from where the user can able to download it after finishing the download it will automatically install the app. Once the Installation finished it should automatically delete the apk from the device. In the same manner when someone download the app from Google Play.
It will be appreciated if you give me a step by step approach, it would be good for me to understand the logic cleary as i'm new to Android Programming.

Please help me on this situation!

Thanks in Advance!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Silent install is ***not*** possible, only when you have root/system rights (which Google Play has). So you can only install the app via the normal way: the user has to accept.

Furthermore downloading can be easily done using the DownloadManager (or do it yourself via `HttpClient`). Both ways allow you to remove it when you want.

Comment: Can we have the system right through code or anything as we are handling the Manufacturing of the device also

Comment: If you are creating the device yourself (and therefore also the Android OS on it), then yes. You should place your app in the Android platform tree and build it with the Android system.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 : Check External storage available or not. If Available

Step 2 : Download the APK as like file and store in a external storage.

Step 3 : Call the following lines

```
try {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(
                                Uri.fromFile(new File(
                                        getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
                                                + "/" + yourfileName)),
                                "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

(A screen will open and ask for User confirmation)

Step 4 : Delete the APK

Installing the APK without user interaction is not possible.

Comment: If the user select to install the app later i think the user will be able to access apk right? My main concern is to restrict user access to apk.

Comment: If you use the DownloadManager and download the APK to the DownloadManager location it won't be possible for the user to find it. (So don't let it download to the external directory.